# how to debug Angular 2 programs

Tags: angular

I am new to web development field and finding difficulty debugging Angular programs. I want to know step by step process so that I can understand better. which is the tool or the editor of Angular. currently, i am using Atom

Comment: Open the dev tools of your browser (F12 on Windows/Linux, Cmd-Alt-I on MacOS). Go to the "Sources" panel. Hit Ctrl-P or Cmd-P to open the file you want to debug. Put a breakpoint, and use the buttons/keyboard shortcuts proposed in the window.

Comment: Thats not good debugging he wants to know how todo this in IDE perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual studio code, Atom etc for development of Angular applications.

### Debug:-

```
If you are using visual studio code for developing angular applications.

then,
1) go to extensions(ctrl+ shift +x) and install debugger for chrome.
2)Then, Go to 'debug' option at the top and click 'Add configuration', then 
  opens 'launch.json'(you can configure it).
3)Then, start debugging by debug option(f5) after putting breakpoints.
```

Second,

### On browser, how to debug(chrome)

```
If chrome,

1) Go to sources.
2) ctrl + p.
3) search your file name. Put breakpoints.
4) Start debugging.
```

Comment: can vs code debugging be configured in combination with `ng serve`?

Comment: After installing extension 'debugger for chrome', and configuring--- "url": "http://localhost:4200"-- in launch.json. You can put breakpoints and start debugging.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, it worked  :)

Comment: Accept it as answer, if it helped you.